# Pass a parameter to another page to prepopulate a text box

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have View page, it has a related list contained within it. However when you use visualforce pages you lose the ability to do some prepopulation with $Action.New, so instead i am trying to get pass a parameter from the original view to the New page, so i can prepopulate a portion of the page.

Is this feasible, currently both the VF pages are using different controllers will i need to make them use the same controller to be able to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View Visualforce page controller your "New" child button can invoke something like:

```
public PageReference newChild() {
    PageReference pr = Page.NewChild;
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    Map<String, String> p = pr.getParameters();
    p.put('parentId', parent.Id); 
    p.put('parentName', parent.Name);
    p.put('text', parent.text);
    return pr;
}
```

and in your NewChild Visualforce page controller you can pickup these parameters using:

```
private void init() {
    Map<String, String> p = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters();
    Id parentId = (Id) p.get('parentId');
    String parentName = p.get('parentName');
    String text = p.get('text');
    // Use the values
}
```

This way the communication between the pages is via the command-line parameters (automatically encoded) rather than by sharing view state (that can be done by sharing the same controller).

As long as there are just a few parameters and they are reasonably small, the command-line parameter approach provides an efficient and clean way to interface between the two pages, and avoids intertwining their controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the solution here:   [how to direct a user to the record type selector from a VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/how-to-direct-a-user-to-the-record-type-selector-from-a-vf-page/12845#12845)

---

How to **set** a **URL Parameter** in the first controller, suppose you have a `customParameter` you want to pass to your next VF Page.

```
string customParameter = 'My Record Type';
pageReference pgRef = new pageReference ('/apex/myVFPage?customParam='+customParameter);
```

The server reads `URL Parameters` like this:  suppose we have a URL

```
string URL='https://na15.salesforce.com/setup/own/groupdetail.jsp?id=00Gi0000001joea&setupid=PublicGroups';
```

The server first takes the string of everything after the `?` and splits by `&` to get a list of `Parameters`.

```
list<string> parameterList = URL.substringAfter('?').split('&');
```

Then you get a map by splitting each parameter by `=`

```
map<string,string> parameterMap = new map<string,string>();

for(string parameter:parameterList)
    parameterMap.put(parameter.substringBefore('='),parameter.substringAfter('='));
```

So the final map in our example equals

```
parameterMap = new map<string,string>{
         'id' => '00Gi0000001joea',
    'setupid' => 'PublicGroups'
}
```

---

To **get** a **URL Parameter** in a controller, use the `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()` method to get a `map<string,string>` of the **URL Parameters**.

```
public class Cntrlr_myVFPage{

    public Cntrlr_myVFPage(){
        string recordTypeName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('customParam');

        // do something with the data.  what happens if you get a NULL result?
        system.debug(system.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'customParam = '+customParam);
        // output:  customParam = My Record Type
    }

}
```

Comment: So, its like anyone could be used: 1). URL Re-Writing, 2). Using Session / Cookie concept 3). Hidden form fields using <apex:inputHidden>. And I think point-1 is being explained here.