# Retrieving records filtered by RecordType in SOQL

Tags: apex, record-type

I've got a custom object `Show__c` that has three different RecordTypes, including one named 'Regular Show'. Using an answer found in [What would be the best approach to get the recordtype id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11968/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-get-the-recordtype-id), I'm grabbing the id of the RecordType using the following:

```
Id regularShowId = Schema.SObjectType.Show__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Regular Show').RecordTypeId;
```

Using SOQL, I want to now get some records out of `Show__c` of that RecordType. I thought the following query would do it:

```
Show__c[] activeShows = [select Show_Display_Name__c, Day__c 
                                         from Show__c 
                                         where Active__c = true 
                                         AND Host__c = :h.id 
                                         AND Start_Date__c <= :date.today() 
                                         AND RecordType = :regularShowId];
```

The Eclipse Force.com IDE complains that this is `No such column 'RecordType' on entity 'Show__c'`, which is not true at all. I did notice in the SFDC object definition, RecordType appears as a "Standard Field" and the column title says "Field Name" instead of "API Name", so perhaps it's not accessible via the API. Is it just not possible to filter by RecordType using SOQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the field on the object is `RecordTypeId`

```
Show__c[] activeShows = [select Show_Display_Name__c, Day__c 
                                         from Show__c 
                                         where Active__c = true 
                                         AND Host__c = :h.id 
                                         AND Start_Date__c <= :date.today() 
                                         AND RecordTypeId = :regularShowId];
```