# How to run a trigger only for specific record types?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have a trigger in place that runs for every order record created. I need this trigger to only run when for specific record types. I am not sure if by my trigger and test class needs to be updated of is only the trigger needs to be updated to reflect this change

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class Test_orderAfterInsert {
public static testmethod void test_method1(){
    Account a  = new Account();
    a.name = 'test';

    insert a;

    case c = new case();
    c.AccountId = a.Id;
    c.origin = 'Phone';

    insert c;

    Orders__c ord = new Orders__c();
    ord.Related_Account__c = a.Id;
    ord.Related_Case__c = c.Id;
    //Orders__c or = new Orders__c();
    //or.Account__c = a.Id;

    insert ord;


}
```

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger orderAfterInsert on Orders__c (after insert) {

string caseId;
list<Case> lstToUpdateCase = new list<Case>();

//Assigning caseid in variable 
for(Orders__c ord : Trigger.New)
{
    caseId = ord.Related_Case__c;
}
//updating case record with the caseid
case c = new case(id = caseId);
c.Order_Created__c = true;
//adding order created into list 
lstToUpdateCase.add(c);

//updating the record through DML operation
if(lstToUpdateCase.Size()>0)
{
    update lstToUpdateCase;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cheryl815, please rephrase the title of your post as a specific question, such a "How to run a trigger for specific record types?"  This makes it easier for other users to understand your objective and find this post when they might ask the same question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> I need this trigger to only run when for specific record types.

Your `orderAfterInsert` trigger will run *every time* an order record is inserted. What you need is to write your trigger such that it **qualifies** order records in `Trigger.new` first.

```
trigger orderAfterInsert on Orders__c (after insert) {

    // Qualify records
    List<Orders__c> qualifiedOrders = new List<Orders__c>();
    for (Orders__c order : Trigger.new) {
        if (order.recordTypeId == '<INSERT DESIRED RECORD TYPE ID(s) HERE>') {
            qualifiedOrders.add(order); 
        }   
    }

    // Now do what you want with the qualified records.
    if (qualifiedRecords.isEmpty() == false) {
        // TODO: Collect case ids from the list of qualified orders.
        // TODO: Set Order_Created__c field of associated cases, and compile in a list of cases.
        // TODO: Perform update of on the list of cases.    
    }
}
```

Another thing I want to address is your for loop where you're setting `caseId`:

```
string caseId;

//Assigning caseid in variable 
for(Orders__c ord : Trigger.New)
{
    caseId = ord.Related_Case__c;
}
```

You'll get unexpected results if `Trigger.new` returns more than one record. Consider gathering your caseIds in a list.

```
List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
for (Order__c order : qualifiedRecords){
    caseIds.add(order.Related_Case__c);
}
```

Comment: You really should not hard code IDs into your code. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11968/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-get-the-recordtype-id

Comment: Your first code block isn't working for me. Everytime I insert in 1 record in 1 of the record types .. it will create records for ALL record types still...

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger definitely needs to be updated and your testmethod should also be updated to reflect the change.

The code would be something like this:

```
trigger orderAfterInsert on Orders__c(after insert) {

string caseId;
Set<ID> RTIds = new Set<ID>();  //set of Record Type IDs to match
list < Case > lstToUpdateCase = new list < Case > ();

for(RecordType rt : [select id from Recordtype where SobjectType='Orders__c' and Name in ('test','foo','bar')]){
    RTIds.add(rt.id);
}
//Assigning caseid in variable 
for (Orders__c ord: Trigger.New) {
    if(if RTIds.contains(ord.Recordtypeid) ){
        caseId = ord.Related_Case__c;
    }
}
//updating case record with the caseid
case c = new
case (id = caseId);
c.Order_Created__c = true;
//adding order created into list 
lstToUpdateCase.add(c);

//updating the record through DML operation
if (lstToUpdateCase.Size() > 0) {
    update lstToUpdateCase;
}
}
```

Comment: Describes are free now, so you could update this answer to reflect that.