# how to refer a record type in a apex class

Tags: apex, batch, class, scheduled-apex, batchapexerrorevent

I'm writing a Apex class to auto delete Case records of record type claims and service failure with created date older than 6 Years here is the code. But i'm failing to Refer the record type in the code can i get some help on it

```
global class DeletecaseBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global DeletecaseBatchClass(){
    }

    global String query;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        query = 'SELECT Id, createddate, RecordType.Name from case where createddate < date.today()-2190 AND RecordType.Name IN ()';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<case>scope){
        delete scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the best approach to get the recordtype id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11968/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-get-the-recordtype-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to them in the same way you do any other property. If you wish to obtain an Id, you can do it this way:

`Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(<MyNameHere>).getRecordTypeId();`

(Note that uses the API Name, not the label)

If you're writing a query, you can do it this way:

`... RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('AAA','BBB')`

I recommend you use `DeveloperName` and not `Name`. RecordType labels can change often but the DeveloperName should seldom, if ever, do.

**PS:** I noticed you are inside of a string, don't forget to escape your inner quotes. For example, in the code above, you would write `(\'AAA\',\'BBB\')`